# Calculate False Acceptance and False Rejection Rates for a biometric system (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix called **(all_output)** (which is the output training and testing Neural Network of 36 users). This matrix contains 36 cells, each cell has **504** values ( as shown in the attaced image)

[image]

the content of each cell of **(all_output)**  is shown in the attached image

[image]

```
                              **___Update__**
```

i will explain how the **(all_output)** has been constructed

After **Neural Network** has been trained, I have used that code in order to test the **Neural Network**

```
% % %     Test the Network  %%%%%%%
     outputs = net(Testing_Gen{i});

     all_output{1,i}=outputs
```

**Testing_Gen**: is a matrix of size (1*36 cells as shown in the attached 
image).

[image]

in order to understand the content of **Testing_Gen** matrix,

for each user, I have 14 test samples(examples), and for each sample 143 features have been extracted and stored in a column.

Each cell in **Testing_Gen** matrix contains the user's test samples and the imposter's test samples ( as shown in the attached image)

[image]

as we could see that one cell is (143 rows **x** 504 columns), the first **14 columns** in each cell is the user's samples ( genuine user's samples) and the remaining columns are the imposter's samples **(490 samples [14*35])**

for example, I have extracted **14 samples** or **examples** for User1 to be used for testing, therefore, the first cell contains the test samples (examples) of **User1** (which are 14) and the imposter's samples as well  **(490 samples [14*35])** in order to calculate the FAR and FRR

I'd like to calculate the False Acceptance Rate **(FAR)**, False Rejection Rate **(FRR)** and Equal Error Rate **(EER)** for this Matrix.

**False Acceptance Rate** is the percentage in which the system incorrectly accepts an imposter as the legitimate user.

For example, to calculate the FAR for User1 all the imposter's samples (which are already stored in **(all_output)** matrix) need to be tested against **User1** and repeat this procedure **36** times.

**False Rejection Rate** displays the percentage in which the authorised user is wrongly rejected by the system.

For example, to calculate the FRR for User1 all his testing samples (which are already stored in **(all_output)** matrix) need to be tested against **User1** and repeat this procedure for each genuine user  **(36 times)**.

**EER** simply can be calculated using this equation **(FAR+FRR)/2**

while calculating **EER**, the **EER's results** should show the necessity of having a balance between **FRR** and **FAR** for the system **(in other words, the value of FAR and FRR should be close to each other as much as possible as my system aim to have a balance between accepting authorised user and rejecting imposters).**

This is the code that I have done so far to calculate FRR

```
%%% performance calculate FAR FRR EER

% %FRR
i=36;  % number of users 
for n=1:i
    counter1=1;
    for t=0:0.01:1     % Threeshold value
        FRRsingletemp=sum(all_output{1,n}(size(all_output{1},1)):size(all_output{1},2)<t)/size(all_output{1},2);
        FRRsingle(counter1)=FRRsingletemp;
        counter1=counter1+1;
    end
    FRR(n,:)=FRRsingle;

end
```

Comment: You should explain better what you have exactly at the matrix all_output. Is it a 1x36 vector? what does the item all_output{1, n} contain? You say that it has 504 values, what are they?

Comment: dear@pablo_worker thank you so much, please read the update and let me know if it make sense now !

Comment: dear@pablo_worker not heard from you mate?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is your question but I cannot agree with your claim

> EER simply can be calculated using this equation (FAR+FRR)/2

FAR (FRR) is not a value, it is a function dependent on threshold.  EER is the value where FAR graph and FRR graph intersect as can be seen [here](http://www.griaulebiometrics.com/en-us/book/understanding-biometrics/evaluation/accuracy/matching/interest/equal).

Comment: link is dead. (FAR + FRR) / 2 is not EER. For example, if FAR = 0, then FRR = 1. If FRR = 0, then FAR = 1. So in this case should EER be 0.5 ?